# Permission denied when changing docker image folder

Tags: docker, permissions

I have a container running docker inside it, but would like to be able to use a mounted folder from the host to store the images etc.

Inside my container I have modified /etc/default/docker to include `DOCKER_OPTS="-g /root/docker"` but when I try to restart the docker service I get the following error:

`/etc/init.d/docker: 1: /etc/default/docker: /root/docker: Permission denied`

I've set the permissions for that folder to fully permissive but I'm still facing the same issue.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you "have a docker container running in which you want to mount images within"?

If so then you just have to supply the volume switch (`-v`) when you start the container, e.g.:

`docker run -d -v /path/to/host/images:/path/to/container/loc [docker_image_id]`

All images (and anything else) within `/path/to/host/images` will be mapped to the docker container at the location: `/path/to/container/loc`.

Comment: I have a dockerised jenkins slave with Docker running inside it which I'm using to build and push docker images. The problem is that the images I'm building are very large and I'm running out of space on the container. I was hoping to have the container store it's docker images somewhere on the host to avoid this problem.